# When doing 3D rotations my angle flips 180 degrees

Tags: trigonometry, transformation, 3d

I'm implementing 3D rotations for a set of 3D circles. To do that I'm using the parametric equation as described in http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParametricEquationOfACircleIn3D/.

It works as expected, but I can't figure out how to mitigate one issue. That is every $180$ degrees my circle flips.

I calculate the normal vector for every circle using $arctan()$. It's value starts from $-0$ then goes to $-\frac{\Pi}{2}$. But then it goes to $\frac{\Pi}{2}$ and decrements down to $-\frac{\Pi}{2}$. And the cycle continues.

How do I make this a continuous progression?

I need this to stop my vertices from flipping.

Comment: Could You please clarify: You are given a circle in 3D? In which form, what parameters are given, or is it that you have points in 3D defining the circle? Did you try to identify the correct quadrant?

Comment: The circle comes from the parametrization as shown in the link in my question.

Comment: But then you already know the normal vector in spherical coordinates, you do not need to compute it, at least not with inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: I don't user spherical coordinates, and I'm not sure how would I get the angle perpendicular to the normal without inverse trig functions. @LutzL

Comment: Please write down in your question how exactly you interpret the 6 parameters of the circle, the webpage is not very detailed in this. Especially interesting would be the interpretation of the 2 parameters of the normal.

Comment: If you are using atan() function, replace it by atan2(). Please note that atan2() takes two arguments: y value and x value. It might not solve your problem as I don't know how you used atan() in computing the normal vector, but atan2() is always favorable than atan().

Comment: @fang you did it! `atan2()` is the solution. Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using atan() function, replace it by atan2(). atan2() is always favorable than atan(). Please note that atan2() takes two arguments: y value and x value.